# Propel and Composer in PHP: no connection

Tags: php, configuration, composer-php, propel, autoload

I've problem in configuring Propel with Composer in my php project.

this is how appears my tree directory:

```
project/
    |--/public_html/index.php
    |--/app/
    |    |--data/
    |    |     |--propel.json
    |    |     |--schema.xml
    |    |--vendor/
    |    |--composer.json
```

In /data/ folder I would store all my propel files, that is generated-classes/ , generated-conf/ and generated-sql/ .

To realize this purpose, with a terminal in /data/  folder, I put the commands in the following sequence:

```
$ propel sql:build
$ propel model:build
$ propel config:convert
```

and all go right.

To make more suitable work, in composer.json I've added this extra feature:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["./data/generated-classes/"]
}
```

so that, almost in theory, putting

```
require '../app/vendor/autoload.php';
```

inside index.php should be enough. Unfortunately, when I try to use one propel classes inside this page, returns the error

> Type: Propel\Runtime\Exception\RuntimeException
>
> Message: No connection defined for database "my_api". Did you forget to define a connection or is it wrong written?
>
> File: 'C:\pathToMyProject'\project\app\vendor\propel\propel\src\Propel\Runtime\ServiceContainer\StandardServiceContainer.php
>
> Line: 279

I thought that propel doesn't find the propel.json file stored in /data/folder.

As extra, if in index.php I simply add

```
require_once  '../app/data/generated-conf/config.php';
```

all goes right.

There's a trick to autoload propel without use this last require_once? (obviously keep the tree as is).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Very curious as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The order of CLI commands is important:

  - `composer install` or `update` to fetch propel
  - then the commands to generate the models with propel
  - then re-scan / re-generate the autoloading files with `composer dump-autoload --optimize`
- You could include the configuration file in the bootstrap process of your application - like you already have.
- Or you could use the `files` directive in Composers `autoload` section
  to define file(s), which should be included on every request.

  Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

  ```
  "autoload": {
      "files": ["./data/generated-conf/config.php"],
      "classmap": ["./data/generated-classes/"]
  }
  ```